# How to handle table JSON/form data from the body of the URL in node.JS and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, request

I have a question in node js express. My question concerns post request with node js express.
I want to make a post request for this data in json form. Below you can find the node js express code and the post I want to do.

**node js express code:**

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.use(express.json()); // built-in middleware for express

app.post('/', function(request, response){
    let myJson = request.body;      // your JSON
    let myValue = request.body.II.A;    // a value from your JSON
    response.send(myJson);   // echo the result back
});

app.listen(3000);
```

======================

The body of the post in  json format:

```
{
            "I" : {
                "Y" : "3",
                "Z" : "2",
                "T" : "1"
            },
            "II" : [
                {
                    "A" : "4",
                    "B" : "5",
                    "C" : {"a": "4", "b" : "6"},
       
                }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: So? What's happening? Does it not work? You forgot to describe the issue you're having. (also note that JSON is a text format, so whenever you're referring to *already parsed* JSON, you're dealing with an object or array, and you should use a variable name that reflects that, not one like "myJson")

Comment: you need to use JSON.parse on the body

Comment: I want to get the II.A in the post request. I added this line:  let myValue = request.body.II.A;       However, I am not getting the value.

Comment: you got the json in the body is II as array of object, try II[0].A @saab19881

Answer (score 0):

use this code to get body data from post API.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var app = express();

app.use(express.json()); // built-in middleware for express
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/', function(request, response){
    let myJson = request.body;      // your JSON
    let myValue = request.body.II.A;    // a value from your JSON
    response.send(myJson);   // echo the result back
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: I tried this solution, it didn't work

Comment: can you share what error is get ?